# How to open a modal aspx page from the devexpress aspxpopupcontrol

Tags: user-controls, modal-dialog, devexpress

I have a button which should open a web form from my project in a modal window. How can I achieve that with the devexpress popup control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Popup Control - Content URL](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/PopupControl/ContentUrl.aspx) to show another webform in the control. open popup on the button's client click event.

example:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popup" runat="server" ContentUrl="~/ContentPageWithTextBox.aspx"
        Top="100" ClientInstanceName="clientPopup" CloseAction="CloseButton">
        <ClientSideEvents Shown="OnShown" />
    </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

Check this [search Result](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=ASPxPopupControl%20contenturl&p=T4%7CP5%7C35&d=16)
**Reference:**
[How to manipulate client-side objects within a ASPxPopupControl with the specified ContentUrl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3928.aspx) - check example also.

Hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code:

```html
<input id="openBtn" type="button" value="Open popup" 
       onclick="myPopup.SetContentUrl('http://www.google.com');myPopup.Show();" />                

<dx:ASPxPopupControl runat="server" ClientInstanceName="myPopup" Modal="True" 
                     CloseAction="CloseButton" Width="500px" Height="400px"/>
```

[ASPxClientPopupControl members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlScriptsASPxClientPopupControlMembersTopicAll)
[ASPxPopupControl members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlASPxPopupControlMembersTopicAll)

Answer (score 0):

See [ASPxPopupControl](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/PopupControl/ModalWindow.aspx) Online Demos and the [Code Central Examples](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=ASPxPopupControl&p=T4%7CP5%7C35&d=16) to learn more on how accomplish this task.